# How can I loop this pattern in javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, formatting

So I'm kind of new to javascript, basically, I have this pattern for positioning DIVs, I know there has to be a way to loop it, because there is a pattern, but I'm just not used to thinking logically like a programmer yet. Could someone provide some insight on how to go about this?

```
        kids[0].style.top = "0px";
        kids[0].style.left = "0px";
        kids[1].style.top = "0px";
        kids[1].style.left = "96px";
        kids[2].style.top = "0px";
        kids[2].style.left = "192px";
        kids[3].style.top = "0px";
        kids[3].style.left = "288px";

        kids[4].style.top = "96px";
        kids[4].style.left = "0px";
        kids[5].style.top = "96px";
        kids[5].style.left = "96px";
        kids[6].style.top = "96px";
        kids[6].style.left = "192px";
        kids[7].style.top = "96px";
        kids[7].style.left = "288px";

        kids[8].style.top = "192px";
        kids[8].style.left = "0px";
        kids[9].style.top = "192px";
        kids[9].style.left = "96px";
        kids[10].style.top = "192px";
        kids[10].style.left = "192px";
        kids[11].style.top = "192px";
        kids[11].style.left = "288px";

        kids[12].style.top = "288px";
        kids[12].style.left = "0px";
        kids[13].style.top = "288px";
        kids[13].style.left = "96px";
        kids[14].style.top = "288px";
        kids[14].style.left = "192px";
        kids[15].style.top = "288px";
        kids[15].style.left = "288px";
```

Comment: Let me ask you this: what is the pattern? If you can determine the pattern then I'm sure you can use a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) to repeat it.

Comment: Further, `kids` is an array and the number in square brackets is the index of the element in that array.

Comment: Right. The tops are the same for each row. For the first, top = 0, second top = 96, third top =192, and fourth top = 288. then each column is position at left = 0 then + 96 for each column after the first. I just don't know how to write a loop for that. Would I need a different one for each section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var kids = [some array/arraylike of elements]

for (var i=0; i < kids.length; i++) {
  kids[i].style.top = 96 * Math.floor(i/4) + "px";
  kids[i].style.left = 96 * (i % 4) + "px";
}
```

The first four kids have 0 as their top.  The next four have 96, third four 192, etc.  So that means for every four elements we iterate, we increase the top by 96px.  Hence floor(i/4) (gives 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2..etc) * 96.

For the .left property, we want 0, 96, 192, 288 to repeat.  So we take the remainder when we divide i by four, and multiply that by 96.

Comment: This worked! Thanks! Let me check my understanding. For the top style, I can see that you are multiplying 96 by what ever the parseInt does and then adding the string "px." Could you explain parseInt a bit? Then the left style you multiply 96 by the remainder of the index of the array divided y 4 then adding the string.

Comment: James: There's no reason to do `parseInt(i / 4, 10)` since you aren't parsing from a string. `Math.floor` would be a better choice.

Comment: What does the "10" do in parseInt/Math.floor?

Comment: @TyTilton the 10 is the base of the number that you want it to return.

Answer (score 0):

you want a loop to iterate over all the kids to set its style.left and style.top properties

so you create two arrays of the possible values for top and left

```
var topvalues =[0, 96, 192, 288];
var leftvalues = [0, 96, 192, 288];
```

and assign them on the loop (`for`) to the appropiate kid indexing with the integer arithmetic operators quotient (`/`) and modulo (`%`)

```
for (var i=0; i<kids.length; i++) {
  kids[i].style.top = topvalues[Math.floor(i/topvalues.length)] + "px";
  kids[i].style.left = leftvalues[i%leftvalues.length] + "px";   
}
```

Comment: Where is the `c` value coming from? And you're going to get `undefined` when indexing `topvalues` or `leftvalues` with non-integers. (if `c === 2` then you'll do `topvalues[0.5]`)

Comment: yep, just copying and pasting, didn't check the code, the reason was to show the idea, not to provide a final code. Now is corrected.

Comment: Would you need two arrays with the same values for this? couldn't use just use one array?

Comment: it's just an example, adapt it to your needs. In fact, for this exact case, you don't even need an array, you can synthesize with a formula `i * 96`

Answer (score 0):

First things first: we need a `for` loop to go through each element in your array. This will give us a way of getting the index (think `0, 1, ..., 14, 15`) for each element.

```
for (var i = 0; i < kids.length; i++) {
  // TODO: do something
}
```

Next, you state that the `top` is going to be `0` for the first row, `96` for the second and so forth. It also looks like each row has 4 items. We can model this using this relationship.

```
var row = Math.floor(i / 4); // Divide i by 4 then remove the remainder
var top = row * 96;
```

This will give you `0` and `0` for the first 4, `1` and `96` for the next 4 and so on. Next, you say you have the same kind of relationship for `left` but for each column. We can model that like this.

```
var column = i % 4; // Get the remainder of i / 4
var left = column * 96;
```

Which will give you `0` and `0` for the first column, `1` and `96` for the second and so on. Finally, we just need to wrap it all up and put a bow on it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < kids.length; i++) {
  var row = Math.floor(i / 4);
  var top = row * 96;
  var column = i % 4;
  var left = column * 96;

  kids[i].style.top = top + 'px'; // Don't forget to say it's in pixels!
  kids[i].style.left = left + 'px';
}
```